# After deploying Laravel project in Heroku MySQL doesn`t work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, heroku, cleardb

I have made my first Laravel project and tried to deploy it to the Heroku. It works, but when I tried to login or register it saying "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL". 
There is my site: http://rocky-river-97869.herokuapp.com/login

[image: After login should look like this:]
Do I have connect PhpMyAdmin separately?
Thank you for you help

Comment: Did you make a new .env file with the correct credentials of your production database? Have you ran composer install , php artisan migrate, .. . If you set your debug to true, you can see the actual error (ofc switch it back of afterwards)

Comment: check your .env file and database connection details

Comment: Right now it says SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL. Everything working in localhost, but after deploing stoped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If yours Laravel project use MySQL you HAVE to use Heroku add-ons CLEARDB.
In the link shows step by step how to solve the problem. It will be useful for newbie like me. 
https://mycodexp.wordpress.com/2016/05/19/deploying-laravel-app-to-heroku-using-mysql-database/